MAUI Mac Catalyst Webview issue: Permission popup not showing
When i am using webview to ask for camera permission in dotnet maui in macbook, the permission to ask for camera permission is not asking in my case.
this is my code:
public OpenCameraPermissionPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = ServiceLocator.GetService<OpenCameraPermissionViewModel>();
    LoadFaceAuthPage();
    Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior(this, new BackButtonBehavior
    {
        IsVisible = false
    });
}

private void LoadFaceAuthPage()
{
    // Your logic to load the web page goes here
    webView.Source = "https://opencampermission.com";
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var vm = (BindingContext as OpenCameraPermissionViewModel);
    await vm.Init();
    webView.Reload();
    foreach (var item in MenuBarItems)
    {
        item.BindingContext = BindingContext;
    }
}



Could you post the relevant code about how you ask for the camera permission?

Have you added NSCameraUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription in info.plist?

Yes I have added, still not able to request for the camera permission

Liquan Shen...I cannot request camera through code...this feature is from the SDK I am using...that ask need to ask for it..not me..I am just using webview to display the url of sdk

Is it a third party sdk? That may not be a MAUI issue.
